# Histogram match between an image and one histogram

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

The matlab function imhistmatch is used to adjust the histogram of a target image A to match N-bin histogram of reference image B.

In matlab, the command to do histogram matching is:

```
hist_match_image = imhistmatch(A,B)
```

The problem is that I don't need to do histogram matching using two images. What I need to do is match the histogram of a target image A to another histogram, which is the mean histogram of a set of reference images.

How to do that in Matlab? should I calculate the mean image of my reference images and use this mean image as the reference image? I don't think it's a correct choice.

Comment: Did you look at `histeq`. That might suit your needs with its second input argument - `histeq(I, hgram)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maybe use `histeq`:

```
Amatch = histeq(A, meanHisto)
```

Never used it; seems like it fits your needs!

Comment: histeq enhances the contrast of images by transforming the values in an intensity image, or the values in the colormap of an indexed image, so that the histogram of the output image approximately matches a specified histogram. I think you are right. I will try your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: I believe @Divakar suggested it first, but I guess that's the way the cookie crumbles.

Comment: @chappjc That's ok! I didn't put enough efforts :)